# Call Multiple Services from Zuul Server API Gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

I have Three Services A,B,C
If I call Service A from Zuul Api gateway than in Api Gateway they call Service B and Service C and give me aggregation response of both services and i want to send that response to Service A.
Is there any way to do that using Zuul.

Comment: I used RxJava to aggregate service calls: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation is not a Zuul task, you need to implement a new Service D and do your aggregation inside.